# A problem about the Linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

$a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is a nonzero vector. $S$ is the linear transformation from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ such that $S(x)=a\times x$（cross）for all vectors $x$. Find the determinant of $S$.

Answer (score 4):

What tells you that $S(a)=0$ (remember $a\neq0$)?